# Remove left padding with geometry package

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to make a checklist for glider flying and I'm unable to tell latex to remove all margins from the page.

This is what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[a6paper, margin={0cm,0cm},twocolumn, layouthoffset=0pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X}
 \rowcolor{gray!50}
 \textbf{ Pre-Flight } \\
 Remove tail wheel (if removable) \\
 Cap \& Sunglasses \\
 Chute on - straps tight \\
 Check Ballast \\
 Px Briefing / Secure back straps \\
 Secure free objects \\
 Check Instruments \\
 Radio on \\
 Controls (Visual) \\
 Wind \\
 Eventualities (Launch failure) \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

However, this is how it looks:

[image]

How do I get rid of the white space on the left side?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should *never* use the `minimal` class to typeset a document.

Comment: What should I use? I searched for other documentclasses and found nothing.

Comment: Use `article` with `\pagestyle{empty}`, but definitely not `minimal`.

Comment: Will do, thanks. May I ask why minimal is bad?

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The space was the atomatic indentation at the beginning of the paragraph. I removed it with `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`